# react router push isn't redirecting to Home component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My react router push isn't redirecting to `Home` component, while I'm passing with props the `Home` path. It seems that the code is correct though.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-example-forked-rmfn5j?file=/src/components/UserDetails.js:0-526

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const ErrorLogin = () => {
  let back = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Error</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => back()}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ErrorLogin;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up React class components and function components. Your example is trying to get the props as you would from a class component, in a function component. To use React router in function components, you need to use the hooks API - in this case, `useHistory`.

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const ErrorLogin = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  let back = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Error</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => back()}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For completeness' sake, here's the equivalent using the class syntax. Note the `withRouter` HOC.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class ErrorLogin extends Component {
  back = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>Error</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
        </p>
        <button onClick={() => this.back()}>Back</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ErrorLogin);
```

Please note that you should probably be using function components going forwards. React router v6 doesn't support class components and the larger React ecosystem is moving away from them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useHistory` hook if you want to use function components.

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const ErrorLogin = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  let back = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Error</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => back()}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the props passed down the component? and also don't you need to have props in component parameters arguments?

```
const ErrorLogin = (props) => {
let back = () => {
 this.props.history.push("/");
 };
  }
```